# How to improve this password validation from OpenCart?

Tags: php, passwords, preg-match, opencart, opencart2.x

Below is the default code from Opencart 2.3.0.2 on github. Its found in approx 5 php files. Currently the password requirements is min 4 and max 20 characters. I want to make it 8 min, one uppercase, one lowercase, and a special character. It has to be similar format so that i can paste over the code.

https://github.com/opencart/opencart/blob/2.2.0.0/upload/catalog/controller/account/password.php

```
        if ((utf8_strlen($this->request->post['password']) < 4) || (utf8_strlen($this->request->post['password']) > 20)) {
            $this->error['password'] = $this->language->get('error_password');
```

Could this work or is there a better one?

```
        if (!preg_match('^(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[@#$%^&amp;+=])(?=\S+$).{8,}$', $this->request->post['password'])) {
            $this->error['password'] = $this->language->get('error_password');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this...

```
if (!preg_match('/(?=^.{8,40}$)((?=.*\d)|(?=.*\W+))(?![.\n])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[a-z]).*$/', html_entity_decode($this->request->post['password'], ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8'))) {
```

This for 8 min. and 40 max. characters, one  uppercase and one lowercase letter. If you wish to check special character, you should add additional regex.